# What is the term for "make more intelligent"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What is the term for "make more intelligent" for example
`Reading books will ... you`?

Comment: Reading books will smarten you up!!

Comment: You need to find a better fitting example sentence. There are many possibilities here.

Comment: It might be more suitable to look for a phrase rather than a single word depending on what you are trying to convey.

Comment: Sorry. there can be a term for 'make more intelligent' only after you've shown that something could make people more intelligent…

I can't prove the negative that no brain-training techniques, no drugs, no physical exercises or diets have been shown to make anyone more intelligent, nevertheless the fact that they haven't should rule the question out of court… should it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a prepositional phrase:

"Smarten you up"
(I just noticed that Josh already thought of that! "Great minds....")

Or to make a noun into an action:

"Intellectualize you."

Remember, language is fun!

Answer (score 1):

I like this word... sort of makes learning "glorious" a the same time:

(in your sentence) "Reading books will *enlighten* you"

> ***[enlighten](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/enlighten)*** from dictionary.com
>
> [en-lahyt-n] 
>   Spell  Syllablesverb (used with object)
>
> 1.
>   to give intellectual or spiritual light to; instruct; impart knowledge to:

Comment: Good word,but this is word is kind of too mature or something.Like epiphany

Answer (score 0):

One option would be "inform."  In a broader sense, "educate" would work as well.

Comment: Please form a better connection between your suggested answer and the user's need. Define the terms and cite source.